# Even and odd headers without fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, exam, etoolbox

I just started to learn latex and I found these headers (I didn't manage to make them with fancyhdr) but I don't understand how to set even and odd pages here. Please help.
I figured out how to change the color, although I don't understand why the package(?) doesn't support dark blue colors.
Or is there a way to include fancyhdr here? please i really try to understand but

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@fullhead}{\hrule}{\color{BlueViolet}\hrule height 1pt \color{BlueViolet}\vskip1pt\hrule height 2pt}{}{}
\patchcmd{\run@fullhead}{\hrule}{\hrule  height 1pt\vskip1pt\hrule height 2pt}{}{}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\runningheadrule
\firstpageheadrule
\firstpageheader{}{\textit{First Exam}}{}
\runningheader{}
{First Exam, Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
{}
\firstpagefooter{}{}{}
\runningfooter{}{}{}

\begin{document}
        test\clearpage
test
\end{document}
```

Comment: see `xcolor` document. https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf. (page.42) DarkBlue in svgnames option.

Comment: The `exam` class uses commands like `\lhead`, `\chead`, etc. which `fancyhdr` also uses, but they are incompatible. Therefore `fancyhdr` cannot be used with `exam`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tom mentions in the comments, you can use `\color{DarkBlue}` if you pass the svgnames option when loading xcolor:

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
```

Of course there are other ways of defining custom colors; see the [package documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor?lang=en).

If you're using the exam class, I think the easiest solution to allowing for different headers/footers on odd and even pages is to use the [ifthen](https://ctan.org/pkg/ifthen?lang=en) package with its `\isodd` test:

```
\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{ Stuff for Odd Page }{ Stuff for Even Page }
```

E.g.:

```
\runningheader%
    {} % left part of header
    {%
        \ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{%
            % center header, odd pages
            {First Exam, Page \thepage\ of \numpages}%
        }{%
            % center header, even pages
            {Page \thepage\ of \numpages, First Exam}%
        }%
    }%
    {} % right part of header
```